# Play sound on the client in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-hosted Blazor application, and I'm trying to figure out how to play a sound on the client side when clicking a button (without touching JavaScript, ugh).

What I've tried:

```cs
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<audio src="alert.wav"></audio>
<button @onclick="@btnAlarm_handleClick">ALARM</button>

@code {

   void btnAlarm_handleClick()
   {
      // ???
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean, play a sound on the *browser*? Which means executing *Javascript*

Comment: C# is on server Side, Javascript is on client side. What you will do is play your sound inside your data center :p

Comment: Did not know :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, in the browser. I was hoping to keep the application pure c#, without introducing javascript in the mix

Comment: @Tomy what you ask is how to call [the play() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) on the audio element. [ASP.NET Core Blazor JavaScript interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1) explains how to call Javascript methods in general. Seriously though, there's no reason to go to the *server* only to come back to the browser and call that method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  "Blazor, despite the name, ends up executing Javascript on the browser". Not true, Blazor compiles down to WebAssembly byte code.

Comment: @Tomy despite the hype, you can't do that with server-side Blazor *NOR* should you want to. There are a *ton* of excellent components and libraries for Javascript. You can use them, or wait for .NET component vendors to replicate them while charging quite a bit of money.

Comment: @Tomy you used the `blazor-server-side` tag, so no. The server sends events to a small browser library that manipulates the DOM. Even when client-side Blazor is released though, you'll still have to use JavaScript packages, or get stuck with clones of those libraries

Comment: @Tomy in any case, Blazor is more React# than WebForms. The component model, the way the applications work, how they are structured are quite similar to React.

Comment: Oops, meant to write `Blazor, despite the hype, ends up executing Javascript on the browser`. And that's why it's not just `Silverlight: Revenge of The Undead` either

Comment: All these comments saying you need to add JavaScript to accomplish what you've described are wrong. All you need to get a working play button is to literally just add **"controls"** to your audio tag: `<audio controls src="alert.wav" />`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Audio is pretty easy without JSInterop in Blazor.

Because Blazor controls elements in the DOM, we can just tell it to switch between two different audio elements, one set to play and one set not to play.

Use your own sound file

Just in case you are concerned that this might download the audio file each time, don't - it doesn't.

Also, although this involves a round trip to the server, the traffic totals just around 770 Bytes for one round trip.

```
<h1>Play sound!</h1>

@code
{
    bool hidden = true;
}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <button @onclick=@(()=>hidden=!hidden)>@(hidden ? "Play" : "Stop")</button>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        @if (!hidden)
        {
            <audio autoplay controls><source src="/crooner2.mp3" /></audio>
        }
        else
        {
            <audio controls muted><source src="/crooner2.mp3" /></audio>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not tested in Safari - because I don't do Apple.

Comment: Is you want to hit the methods and events associated with the audio object, you'll have to use JSInterop. For example, it's good to know when it's done playing, or has buffered enough to play at all when it uses byte ranges.

Answer (score 8):

In this scenario, the only way to tell the `<audio>` element to start playing is ultimately ... through Javascript.

There are two ways; simple, and not-quite-so-simple.

**(1)** The simple way, using inline JS:

```
<audio id="sound" src="/media/alert.wav" />

<button onclick="document.getElementById('sound').play()">Play through Javascript</button>
```

**(2)** The not-quite-so-simple way, by triggering an event through SignalR on the server application, which then through SignalR sends back a command to invoke a JS function, which you need to have created beforehand in a particular way:

```
<audio id="sound" src="/media/alert.wav" />

<button @onclick="@ClickHandler">Play through C#</button>

@code {
    async void ClickHandler()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("PlaySound"); // this calls "window.PlaySound()"
    }
}
```

*Also create this file:* /js/PlaySound.js

```
window.PlaySound = function() {
  document.getElementById('sound').play();
}
```

*Also edit this file:* /Pages/_Host.cshtml

```
<head>
    <!-- Various other tags -->
    <script src="/js/PlaySound.js"></script>
</head>
```

Bottom line:

- Accept that you will need Javascript to do things like this.
- Don't bother using Blazor to call JS, unless you absolutely need Server Side stuff to determine if the Javascript code is going to be called and/or how.

Comment: Requires adding @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime to the razor file

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar, but used src:

Sample from .Net user group demo, dropdown of mp3's to select from.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env
@inject AppState State

<h3>Media</h3>

<select @onchange="PlayFile" value="@State.LastSong">
    @foreach (var f in new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(env.WebRootPath + "/sounds").GetFiles("*.mp3"))
    {
        <option value="/sounds/@f.Name">@f.Name</option>
    }
</select>

<audio src="@_currentFile" autoplay></audio>

@code {

    private string _currentFile = "";

    private void PlayFile(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var song = e.Value.ToString();

        _currentFile = song;
        State.SetSong(song);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can easily play sound/audio files in Blazor using HTML audio element without touching JavaScript. I added some extra stuff incase needed.

Preview:
[image]

---

Solution steps:

- Load the sound files from the wwwroot eg. `/wwwroot/alarms/` into a list of class `Sound` storing the sound url and size of each.
- Show all sound files in a HTML list with a play icon button for playing the sound.
- Format file sizes using `FormatSize` function to a nice format.
- Show or hide the audio player.

Implementation:

```razor
@page "/"
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env

<audio src="@soundUrl" controls="@showPlayer" autoplay>
    Your browser does not support the html audio tag.
</audio>

@if (alarmList != null)
{
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        @foreach (var alarm in alarmList)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
                @(alarmList.IndexOf(alarm) + 1).
                @alarm.Name,
                @FormatSize(alarm.Length)
                <span onclick="@(() => PlayAudio(alarm.Url))"
                      class="text-primary oi oi-play-circle me-2" role="button">
                </span>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <label>Show player: </label>
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="showPlayer"/>
}
```

```cs
@code
{
    private Guid soundKey = Guid.NewGuid();
    private List<Sound> alarmList = new();
    private string soundUrl { get; set; }
    private readonly string soundFolder = "alarms";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var path = $"{env.WebRootPath}\\{soundFolder}\\";
        var d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = d.GetFiles();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            alarmList.Add(new Sound
            {
                Name = file.Name,
                Url = $"/{soundFolder}/{file.Name}",
                Length = file.Length
            });
        }
    }

    private void PlayAudio(string url)
    {
        // reload the player with url
        soundKey = Guid.NewGuid(); 
        soundUrl = url;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public class Sound
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public long Length { get; set; }
    }

    private string FormatSize(long bytes)
    {
        var counter = 0;
        decimal number = bytes;
        string[] suffixes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" };

        while (Math.Round(number / 1024) >= 1)
        {
            number = number / 1024;
            counter++;
        }

        return $"{number:n1}{suffixes[counter]}";
    }
}
```

Extra:
If you want to show sound files in a HTML table and also be able to delete the sound files, look into my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411278/8316900

Comment: Would this still work if you tried to replay the same file? i.e. you clicked on a link multiple times, does it play it each time it is clicked?  In my tests, it only runs the first time.. anyway to force a .play() call?