# Blazor: How to play or delete an audio file in a list?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm making a list where files are loaded in the blazor server app. I want 2 things to be possible when a file on the list is clicked.
1: I can play the audio now. 2: Delete the audio file from the folder.

Right now, when the site loads, I have a list of the files in the path, and and audio player in the cell on the right.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
        <tbody>
            @if (filesList != null && filesList.Count > 0)
                {
                    int auF = 0;  
                    @foreach (string file in filesList)
                    {    auF++;
                         <tr> <td>
                         <span>@auF.</span>
                         <span @onclick="@(e=>readFile(file))"style="cursor:pointer;">@file</span>
                         </td> <td>
                         <audio controls="controls">
                             <source src="@file">
                         </audio>
                         </td> </tr>
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>No Files</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
@code{
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    string path = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\path"}";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            filesList.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }
  
    @*Just here to show list*@
    public void readFile(string fileName)
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make a file clickable in the table, so that I can get to choose to either play it or delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer list the audio files in the table as seen from your code. You can select their names or the icon play button to play the audio. You can delete the file from folder by selecting the delete icon button. Before delete it will show a prompt to confirm before deletion.

Note: Store your files in `wwwroot` eg. in this example `wwwroot/audio/` is used.

Solution:
[image: How to list audio in a table in blazor and also delete]

Implementation:

```razor
@page "/"
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<audio src="@audioUrl" controls="@showPlayer" autoplay>
    Your browser does not support the html audio tag.
</audio>

<table class="table table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Modified</th>
        <th scope="col">Size</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if (audioList.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (var file in audioList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@(audioList.IndexOf(file) + 1)</td>
                <td>
                    <a @onclick="@(() => PlayAudio(file.Url))"
                       class="link-primary"
                       role="button">
                        @file.Name
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>@file.LastModified.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm")</td>
                <td>@FormatSize(file.Length)</td>
                <td>
                    <span @onclick="() => PlayAudio(file.Url)"
                          class="text-primary oi oi-play-circle me-2" aria-hidden="true" role="button">
                    </span>
                    <span @onclick="() => DeleteAudio(file)"
                          class="text-danger oi oi-trash" aria-hidden="true" role="button">
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">No files</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
<label>Show player: </label>
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="showPlayer"/>
```

```cs
@code{
    private bool showPlayer = true;
    readonly List<AudioFile> audioList = new();
    private string audioUrl { get; set; }
    readonly string audioFolderName = "audio";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var path = $"{env.WebRootPath}\\{audioFolderName}\\";
        var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
        ;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            audioList.Add(new AudioFile
            {
                Name = file.Name,
                Url = $"/audio/{file.Name}",
                Length = file.Length,
                LastModified = file.LastWriteTime,
                Path = file.FullName
            });
        }
    }

    private void PlayAudio(string url)
    {
        audioUrl = url;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async Task DeleteAudio(AudioFile audio)
    {
        var isConfirmed = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>(
            "confirm", "Are you sure you want delete the file?");
        if (isConfirmed)
        {
            if (File.Exists(audio.Path))
            {
                File.Delete(audio.Path);
                audioList.Remove(audio);
                if (audioUrl.Equals(audio.Url))
                {
                    audioUrl = string.Empty;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class AudioFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public long Length { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }

    private string FormatSize(long bytes)
    {
        var counter = 0;
        decimal number = bytes;
        string[] suffixes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" };

        while (Math.Round(number / 1024) >= 1)
        {
            number = number / 1024;
            counter++;
        }

        return $"{number:n1}{suffixes[counter]}";
    }
}
```